# Teradata SQL - Where clause and conditions depending on conditions

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, teradata, where-clause

[image]

Note- not all columns are listed here in the Master Table for brevity.
Psuedo code of the where clause -

[image] 
[image]

My where clause goes like this (with some selected conditions) -

1. customer_country in ('A','B','C','D') AND
2. ship_country = 'A' AND customer_number <> 'A2' OR
3. ship_country = 'B' AND customer_number <> 'B2' OR
4. ship_country = 'C' AND customer_number NOT IN ('C1', 'C2') AND
5. ship_date between dates.

But this appears to give incorrect answer. Perhaps something is wrong with the logic. Please advice.

Comment: Edit your question instead of putting valuable information as comments.

Comment: thanks jarlh, followed your suggestion

Comment: `where not (ship_country = 'A' and customer_number = 'A2') and not (...`

Comment: I got this error message - Executed as Multiple statements.  
STATEMENT 1: DATABASE  completed. 0 rows processed. Elapsed time = 00:00:00.531 
STATEMENT 2: Select Statement failed.  Failed [3134 : HY008] The request was aborted by an ABORT SESSION command.

Comment: Where is the filed `customer_country` on your `master` table?

Comment: The order of precednce is `NOT-AND-OR`, you probably need to add brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM [MASTER]
WHERE 
    Ship_country in ('A','B','C','D')
AND
    (   
        (customer_number <> 'A2')
    OR
        (customer_number <> 'B2')
    OR
        (customer_number NOT IN ('C1', 'C2'))
    )
```